# Maple - Integration returns undefined for very simple and possible integrations

Tags: maple

This is a question about maple producing undefined errors.

The code below should give the result 0 but instead maple chooses to label it "undefined".

```
(nj*(nj-1))*(int(N^(ni+nj-2),N=-1..1));
ni:=0;  nj:=0;
```

Since nj=0 you can see quite clearly that even before the integral, the answer is 0 x integral.

The integral is possible to do and doing it by hand it gives you (-1/N) evaluated between 1 and -1
so substituting in (-1/1)-(-1/-1) which is -1-1 = -2).

The overall answer is given by 0x-2 which is 0.

Maple returns **undefined**.

However if you take a subsection of that code (just the integral)

```
 (int(N^(ni+nj-2),N=-1..1)) or even (int(N^(-2),N=-1..1))
```

then maple returns **infinity**.

Neither of these are correct.

Can anyone explain to me why this happens?
I think others are likely to come across a similar issue because it is such a simple maple procedure. Yet it gives a confusing result.

Comment: For the second case, have a look at the plot of [the function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x^%28-2%29+x%3D-1..1). The result is indeed inf.

Comment: And you are forcing 0 * Inf, which doesn't make any sense, so the result is `Undefined` for the first case.

Comment: Check out [Integrability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability). The function is not bounded on the [-1, 1] interval.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way that I can somehow add limits into my code in order to make it work?
It's part of a much larger program that I've written and I isolated this as the line that was causing a problem at ni=nj=0 (but for values of ni and nj above zero it holds - I use these higher values in a loop) so I was hoping to keep the code in somehow if there's a way to modify it. How would you recommend I change it?

Comment: I assume ni and nj are natural number? Then if ni + nj - 2 is negative, and if ni + nj - 2 is odd then [Cauchy principle value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) assumption holds, which allow the function to be integrable from negative to positive although the function may not be bounded; for the case ni + nj - 2 is even (and negative), then the function is not integrable from negative to positive number. If ni + nj - 2 >= 0, then it should be integrable (the case = 0 is a bit special since 0^0 is undefined, but from what I read, it should be OK).

Comment: @EmilyFinnerty Afaik you can construct if statements in Maple. As Maple cannot know what you want, you should explicitly give these instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already shared in the comments, 0 times infinity is undefined, see e.g. [Why is infinity multiplied by zero not an easy zero answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28940/why-is-infinity-multiplied-by-zero-not-an-easy-zero-answer)

To still keep your Maple sheet as intact as possible, you can always include if-statements in the code, which is really easy

```
if nj = 0 then
 #do something
end if;
```

However, you should always check if you are doing the right thing mathematically, as Maple does output *Undefined* for a reason!